# Postgresql. Получение результата now() - timestamp в миллисекундах

Tags: sql, postgresql

Создал таблицу:

```
create table test(id integer,buf integer, start timestamp);
```

Вставил строку:

```
insert into test values(1,100,now());
```

Теперь мне как-то нужно получить разность текущего времени и времени, записанного в столбце start по id, результат типа integer. 
Выяснил, что текущее время в миллисекундах типа double могу получить с помощью запроса select extract(from epoch now()); Далее у меня никак получается релиазовать задуманное. Пробывал нечто подобное:

```
select extract(epoch from st (select start as st from test where id=1)) as foo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разницу между двумя датами можно получить простым вычитанием, такой оператор предоставляется в `postgresql`. Результатом будет значение типа `interval`, так же подходящее для использования в функции `extract`.

```
select extract(epoch from now() - "start") * 1000 as msdiff 
from test;
```

`extract` `epoch` обозначает время в секундах, следовательно для значения в микросекундах его необходимо умножить на 1000.

Для перевода значения в int выберите подходящий вам способ округления double и приведите его к int:

```
select round(extract(epoch from now() - "start") * 1000)::int as msdiff 
from test;
```

Возможно использовать `round` для математического округления, `trunc` для отбрасывания дробной части, `ceil` и `floor` для округления вверх и вниз соответственно.